# How to log messages within snowflake event table from procedure written in snowflake scripting?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to `log messages generated by my stored procedure` into an `event table in Snowflake`. For that I am using scripts as below to create and set an event table first and then script for my procedure is also mentioned.

As per the documentation `system$log` function can be used to log messages to event table for `procedures written in Snowflake Scripting`. But at the end I am not able to capture anything in my event table. Like when I do a select on it, the result is an empty event table.

Can anyone please help me with what I am doing wrong here?

How do I make sure that any `exception` while execution of a SQL also gets captured in the event table?

**EDIT - CHANGED LOG LEVEL TO INFO FROM ERROR IN SET LOGLEVEL SCRIPT; STILL NOTHING CAPTURED IN EVENT TABLE IN CASE OF EXCEPTION**

```
CREATE EVENT TABLE MYDB.MYSCHEMA.LOGGING_TABLE;

ALTER ACCOUNT SET EVENT_TABLE = MYDB.MYSCHEMA.LOGGING_TABLE;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDB.MYSCHEMA.TEST()
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE
  accumulator VARCHAR;
  res RESULTSET DEFAULT ( select CONCAT_WS('.', TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME) as FQ_TABLE_NAME
                            from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES 
                            where TABLE_TYPE = 'EXTERNAL TABLE' and DELETED is null ) ;
  c1 CURSOR FOR res;
BEGIN
  SYSTEM$LOG('INFO', 'SUCCESSFUL');
  insert into table1 (fq_name, scripts) values (null, 'USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;');
  FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
    accumulator := row_variable.FQ_TABLE_NAME;
    insert into table1 (fq_name, scripts) select :accumulator, get_ddl('table', :accumulator);
    SYSTEM$LOG('INFO', 'DDL FOR TABLE &{:accumulator} SUCCESSFUL!');
  END FOR;
  RETURN 'SUCCESS';
END;
$$
;


ALTER PROCEDURE MYDB.MYSCHEMA.TEST() SET LOG_LEVEL = INFO;

CALL MYDB.MYSCHEMA.TEST();

SELECT * FROM MYDB.MYSCHEMA.LOGGING_TABLE;
```

Comment: You’ve set the log level for your proc to ERROR but your proc is only generating INFO level events - so they are not going to get captured. You need to review the hierarchy of log levels: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#label-log-level

Comment: `@NickW` - Sure thats there in script, but I quickly tried changing log level to Info but still nothing got captured.

Comment: As you’ve now significantly changed your question, are you still asking how to get anything to write to the event table or are you just asking how to write exceptions to the event table?

Comment: `@NickW` - How to write exceptions to event table is what I intend to ask. Previous version of question might not have made it clear.

Comment: Put an exception handler in your code and within that write to your event table